# Can not make header sticky in Salesforce LWC - Data table

Tags: html, css, salesforce, lwc

I am trying to make my header sticky with overriding css with "Top:0"
it seems to be over written by something else.
I did try !Important but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: By what is it being overwritten if you look at the header using DevTools?

Answer (score 0):

slds-table--header-fixed_container : add this class on div by specifying the height for div

slds-table--header-fixed : add this class to table

slds-cell-fixed: add this class to  tag.

Comment: Hi Santosh, Thank you so much for your answer. I checked that my div already has
slds-table--header-fixed_container :
And My table already has slds-table--header-fixed 
How do I add slds-cell-fixed to class tag ?

I have a css file in static resources to override existing CSS.
I am new to SF front end. I would really appreciate your help

Comment: The Div of cell already has the slds-cell-fixed: class . I am using chrome dev tool to see what else could be over writing it. But I don't see anything else.

Answer (score -1):

Please try like this. It works.

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>    
</template>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).